# How do I have more than 1 Texture2d falling from the top of the screen in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna

I am currently working on a game project where objects fall from the top of the screen and the person at the bottom needs to catch the right objects.

```
Texture2D blockTexture;

List<Vector2> blockPositions = new List<Vector2>();
float BlockSpawnProbability = 0.01f;
const int BlockFallSpeed = 2;
```

The following is to spawn new falling blocks

```
if (random.NextDouble() < BlockSpawnProbability)
{
 float x = (float)random.NextDouble() *
 (Window.ClientBounds.Width - blockTexture.Width);
 blockPositions.Add(new Vector2(x, -blockTexture.Height));
}


personHit = false;
for (int i = 0; i < blockPositions.Count; i++)
 {
  // Animate this block falling
blockPositions[i] =
 new Vector2(blockPositions[i].X,
             blockPositions[i].Y + BlockFallSpeed);
// Get the bounding rectangle of this block
Rectangle sprite =
new Rectangle((int)blockPositions[i].X, (int)blockPositions[i].Y,
                    blockTexture.Width, blockTexture.Height);

// check collision with person
if (personRectangle.Intersects(sprite))
  personHit = true;
if (blockPositions[i].Y > Window.ClientBounds.Height)
  {
   blockPositions.RemoveAt(i);
   i--;
  }
 }
 base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

To draw the blocks

```
foreach (Vector2 blockPosition in blockPositions)
spriteBatch.Draw(blockTexture, blockPosition, Color.White);
```

I understand if someone says they don't give our answers here but I just want some help with this and how to do it..

How can I make an array where the objects get picked randomly and they fall from the screen instead of adding the Texture2Ds one by one.

I did try to find tutorials on this but I couldn't..
I'll appreciate any help given.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Can you refine it? As I can see you doing right heare: use one texture and list of positions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and Im sorry if I was unclear. 
Currently in the game I have one block falling from the top to bottom of the screen... I would like to make 3-4 different objects falling. Such as an apple and a banana as well as these blocks..
But I just don't know how to add the other objects in....
I thought it would be easier if I make an array of objects and they get picked randomly and fall, but I need help with that.

Answer (score 0):

In my games I'm allways have same pattern (less or more similar).

I have one class for item class to keep there general properties:

```
public class ItemClass
{
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
    public int Points;
    public Texture2D Texture;

    public ItemClass(int pID, int pName, int pPoints, int pTetxure2D)
    {
        this.ID = pID;
        this.Name = pName;
        this.Points = pPoints;
        this.Texture = pTexture;
    }

    public Item New()
    {
        return new Item(this.ID);
    }
}
```

And one class for item instance for keep individual properties:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ClassID;
    public Vector2D Position;

    public Item(int pClassID)
    {
        this.ClassID = pClassID;
    }
}
```

Main parts of game class:

```
public CoolGame : Game
{
    private Dictionary<int, ItemClass> itemClasses; // each item class should nave unique ID
    private List<Item> items; // real items; better also make as dictionary with unique ID for each
    private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    // call in LoadContent to register all item classes you want use in game
    private LoadItemClasses()
    {
        this.itemClasses = new Dictionary<int, ItemClass>();
        this.itemClasses.Add(0, new ItemClass(0, "Silver coin", 1, silver_coin_texture));
        this.itemClasses.Add(1, new ItemClass(1, "Gold Coin", 3, gold_coin_texture));
        this.itemClasses.Add(2, new ItemClass(2, "Diamond", 10, diamond_texture));
        this.itemClasses.Add(3, new ItemClass(3, "Anchor", -5, anchor_texture));
        /// and so on...

        this.items = new List<Item>();
    }

    // call to create real item that you can draw and catch
    private void CreateRandomItem()
    {
        Vector2D randomPosition = ...;
        int randomItemClassID = ...;
        ItemClass itemClass = this.itemClasses[randomItemClassID];
        Item item = itemClass.New();
        item.Position = randomPosition;
        this.items.Add(item);
    }

    private void UpdateItems()
    {
        foreach (Item item in this.items)
        {
            // update item position, check collision and so on
        }
    }

    // you use position from item, but texture from itemClass, so you can use only one Texture2D object for whole your items of this class
    private void DrawItems()
    {
        ItemClass itemClass = null;
        this.spriteBatch.Begin();
        foreach (Item item in this.items)
        {
            itemClass = this.itemClasses[item.ClassID];
            spriteBatch.Draw(itemClass.Texture, item.Position, color.White);
        }

        this.spriteBatch.End();
    }
}
```

Also google some about tile maps to increase performance of your game.